# LESS css: trying to use the red, green, and blue functions to get rgb values and then insert into gradient

Tags: css, function, less

I'm trying to pull individual r, g, b values from preferably a hex value, then insert those values into a background gradient. The idea is that I don't have to fiddle around with individual rgb values. I'm trying to use the red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color) functions but the error I get is: **error evaluating function `rgb`: color functions take numbers as parameters**

```
@color: #E28141;

.test-gradient (@color, @topalpha, @topstop, @bottomalpha, @bottomstop) {
@red1:red(@color);
@green1:green(@color);
@blue1:blue(@color);

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
}
```

Martin pointed out that the above code actually works so I'm including the actual mixin I'm trying to use:

```
.test-gradient (@color, @topalpha, @topstop, @bottomalpha, @bottomstop) {
@red1:red(@color); @green1:green(@color); @blue1:blue(@color);
background: rgb(@red1,@green1,@blue1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(@topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha)), color-stop(@bottomstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems to work fine to me,

i tried this:

```
.test-gradient(@color, .5, 10%, .9, 90%);
```

and the output was:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(226, 129, 65, 0.5) 10%, rgba(226, 129, 65, 0.9) 90%);
```

so I am not sure what you were passing in the variables, maybe you can show us an example that produces the error.

### Edit:

you just had some typos (used `green` insted of `@green` once and `@@red` in another place). This should work now:

```
.test-gradient (@color, @topalpha, @topstop, @bottomalpha, @bottomstop) {
@red1:red(@color);
@green1:green(@color);
@blue1:blue(@color);
background: rgb(@red1, @green1, @blue1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(@topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha)), color-stop(@bottomstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@topalpha) @topstop,rgba(@red1,@green1,@blue1,@bottomalpha) @bottomstop);
}
```

### Note:

functions `tint`, `shade`, `multiply`, `screen`, `overlay`, `hardlight`, `difference`, `exclusion`, `average`, `negation`, `softlight`, `red`, `green`, `blue` and `contrast` have been only introduced in **[LESS 1.3.1](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#131)**.

In older versions of LESS for example

```
red(#E28141)
```

will return

```
red(#E28141)
```

instead of the number

```
226
```

Comment: I've included the full mixin that I've been trying to use that has been giving me an error. edit: I've also tried running the simplified code and that is giving me the same error.

Comment: Martin, I noticed the typos and with the corrected code, and even when I run the simplified example I'm still receiving the error...

Comment: I see this now ... it is a problem in older versions of LESS, since 1.3.1 it works fine, I recomand using a newer version of LESS, but I will still look into the error now.

Comment: Yes ... the **new functions tint, shade, multiply, screen, overlay, hardlight, difference, exclusion, average, negation, softlight, red, green, blue, contrast** have been only introduced in version 1.3.1 see https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Martin, thanks to you I checked what version I was running... 1.2.1! linked to 1.3.3 and it works perfectly now. thanks again